# Failure in SSL library on using cipher

Tags: java, android, sockets, encryption, ssl

I have created a ssl socket connection with my server. The server sends me the RC4 key and i use the key to create a cipher and bind it to the input and output streams of the existing socket. I am getting the following error on trying to read from the input stream:

javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x32fbf8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Is it possible that the decryption is not working properly or the RC4 key cipher is not correct. what are the reasons for such an error. I am doing it in an app on android 2.3.3.

One more query, does android 2.3.3 support sslv23(openssl) . If so how can instantiate the same ?(In windows client, i set the session context with the rc4 key and it works perfectly fine)

I am new to java and android and come from VC++ background. 
Experts and programmers please enlighten me on my queries. My code is as follows:

```
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
/*   some code to initialize ssl context  */
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketfactory =  sslContext.getSocketFactory();
sock = (SSLSocket) sslSocketfactory.createSocket(host,port1);
sock.setSoTimeout(12000);

is = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream(),
                                 16384));
os = sock.getOutputStream();
/*  some more code using above mentioned is and os to recieve rc4 key and 
    write it into a byte array   */

SecretKey key2 = new SecretKeySpec(reverserRc4InBytes, 0, reverserRc4InBytes.length, "RC4");
Cipher cipherOS = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
cipherOS.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key2);


Cipher cipherIS = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
cipherIS.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key2);
cos = new CipherOutputStream(os,cipherOS);
cis = new CipherInputStream(is,cipherIS);
```

Comment: Why does the server send you an RC4 key if you're already using SSL/TLS?

Comment: i am trying to do it the same way as i have done for windows client.the protocol is : 1. create a client socket and establish connection,receive the rc4 key and use the rc4 key to decrypt further communication. so i decided to create a cipher with the received key and bind use the cipher input stream. am i going wrong?

Comment: Why encrypt twice, via SSL/TLS and using your own extra key (which you seem to pass in clear over your SSL/TLS channel anyway), independently of Windows, Java or any other language/platform? It's even worse if you're only encrypting once (without underlying SSL/TLS) on your existing client, by passing the key directly at the beginning of the communication.

Comment: Was the server implemented using an existing SSL/TLS stack, or was it "home made" encryption using the same cipher principle?

Comment: The server is implemented in C and using an existing SSL stack .. sslv23 to be specific. Is my way of implementing the same at client end sound good? Am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: I cant change the encryption techniques as it is a legacy server. the ssl socket connection is used for receiving the rc4 key and rc4key decryption is used for further data encryption henceforth.How do i set the RC4 key to the existing ssl context?

Comment: With Java the socket is already encrypted/decrypted by the stack. Are you trying to encrypt something over the already protected SSL channel or are you trying to implement part of the SSL protocol?

Comment: I am trying to encrypt using the Rc4 key over the ssl channel.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're first making an SSL/TLS connection to exchange the RC4 key somehow, and then you're using it to encipher and decipher the result, instead of letting the SSL/TLS stack do it all for you. (It's clearly unnecessarily convoluted, and it's not clear how secure this is, since SSL/TLS provides you with more than encryption, in particular with integrity.)

> The server is implemented in C and using an existing SSL stack ..
> sslv23 to be specific.

SSLv23 isn't really a "stack" (by "stack" I mean an implementation: JSSE, OpenSSL, .Net's Security API, ...). SSLv23 usually refers to SSLv3 where [the initial Client Hello message is wrapped in SSLv2 format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-E). This wrapping happens on the client side, for clients that supports both SSLv3 and SSLv3/TLSv1.x. Which versions the server support should be fixed, in particular, you shouldn't need to use that trick if your server supports SSLv3 and above. (Note that the JSSE supports the v2 wrapped Client Hello format, but doesn't actually support SSLv2. I guess this is also the case for Android.)

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x32fbf8: Failure
> in SSL library, usually a protocol error

This indicates that something incompatible is happening between your server and the client. There can be a few reasons for this:

- Your server only supports SSLv2 (not 3). Let's assume your server supports at least SSLv3 (you can check whether the handshake completes using Wireshark, for example.)
- There's a more general problem with the SSL/TLS implementation on the server. (You could attempt to connect to it using other tools, such as `openssl s_client`, at least to see if the connection can be established.)
- Your key exchange protocol expects the SSL/TLS connection to end there, while leaving your manual handling of the connection on a plain TCP socket afterwards. You may have to use your `Socket` as an `SSLSocket` only during the section where SSL/TLS is used and revert back to the plain `Socket` afterwards. ()

  You can try to establish a plain socket to your server, upgrade it to an `SSLSocket` using [`createSocket (Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.Socket,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29) with `autoClose=false` and get the I/O from the plain socket to do your manual encryption.

  I would assume that this should have caused other problems on the `SSLSocket` side, especially when the server closes its side of the SSL/TLS connection, though. This is just a guess, this approach might work.

Anyway, I don't think the problems you're seeing have anything to do with your using `Cipher` manually from your `SSLSocket`'s I/O streams, since the exception happens at the underlying layer, which should be hidden as far as the data you read/write there is concerned.

Comment: I am sorry my attempt to reply ended up editing your post. How can i revert it back.

Comment: >> From what I understand, you're first making an SSL/TLS connection >> to exchange the RC4 key > somehow, and then you're using it to  >> encipher and decipher the result, instead of letting the SSL/TLS >> stack do it all for you.

You are absolutely right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. They are of great help .We already have an existing windows client which interacts with the server 1.Create SSL connection 2.receive rc4(openssl) key 3.set the the key to the session context (using open ssl functions EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init,EVP_CipherInit_ex)4. Communicate with the server (Server is RFB) How should i attempt to set the rc4 key to the already existing ssl socket connection?

Comment: @grv You can't set the RC4 key to the existing socket connection. The SSL handshake establishes its own key. I am wondering more and more whether you have really understood this assignment correctly, and also whether it is really worth doing. The RC4 cipher is by no means the best one going around now.

Comment: @EJP Thanks!! So in that case how should i approach if i need to use a Rc4 key which i am supposed to receive from the server to decrypt futher communication with the server. The server sends me the rc4 key only on a ssl socket connection.

Comment: What you seem to be doing looks like a home-made brew of PSK cipher suite, but without the pre-sharing... This system is clearly deviating from the standard specifications, so don't expect compatibility with anything. If you want to achieve your goal, you may have to take an existing TLS implementation and tweak it quite heavily. Considering that this is certainly going to be a difficult job, and that it's likely to weaken its security, I'd consider altering the server and the existing client to make it use SSL/TLS normally. Both sound like substantial tasks, but the latter sounds easier to do

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have understood your assignment properly. *Either* you should be using SSL *or* you need to implement this home-grown cipher.

Or else you should look for a saner job ;-)